# Run 2 python scripts for specified amount of time, each separately

Tags: python

I have two python scripts as separate file. say for example hello.py and hello1.py. lets take my total execution time is 100 seconds. So i want hello.py to execute for first 60 sec and hello1.py to execute for 40 secs. So how to spilt it and do?

Comment: What is the reason of the time limitation(s)?

Comment: actually i want to launch a mixed attack. Half bogus and half genuine. i already i have scripts for bogus and genuine separately in python. now to launch a mixed attack i want to execute hello.py say for 60 sec and automatically the second script hello1.py should execute for remaining 40 sec.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alarms to interrupt code after it has been running for a while. The advantage is that the code being run need not be aware of the time limits. The downside is that it has no chance to terminate gracefully (although you could catch the Stop exception to do so).

```
import signal
import time

def task(name):
    """Generic task -- print out name once a second."""
    while True:
        print(name)
        time.sleep(1)

class Stop(Exception):
    """Raised to stop a running task."""
    pass

def onAlarm(signum, frame):
    """Alarm signal handler."""
    raise Stop

def run(function, seconds):
    """Run a function for a specified number of seconds."""

    # install our alarm handler
    savedHandler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, onAlarm)

    # request an alarm after the specified numbers of seconds
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, seconds)

    # run the function
    try:
        function()
    except Stop:
        pass

    # restore the saved timeout handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, savedHandler)

# run hello for 6 seconds
run(lambda: task("hello"), 6)

# run hello1 for 4 seconds
run(lambda: task("hello1"), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me define two python scripts, temp4.py and temp5.py. Contents:

temp4.py

```
def f1():
 print 'hello'
```

temp5.py

```
    def f2():
        print 'hello1'
```

a final script temp5.py. this will measure time and run the scripts accordingly. change the times. here, both scripts will run for 10 seconds.

```
        from temp4 import f1
        from temp5 import f2
        from timeit import default_timer as timer

        start = timer()

        while (timer()-start)<10:
            f1()
            print timer()-start

        while (timer()-start)<20: #add timings here
            f2()
            print timer()-start
```

Please add the second time to the timer. So the first time will be 60, second will be 100.

Comment: Only the first while loop is running...and it prints hello for 10 seconds...i want to run temp4.py for 60 seconds and temp5.py for 40 seconds